# JQuery Ajax in Chrome sends GET instead of POST, but in Edge it sends correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

The following code triggers a GET Method instead of POST.

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',url: 'http://localhost:8000/DoAsync',data: {i:e},dataType: 'script'            
    });
```

It's happened in Chrome.

[image]

But, while I use the same code in Edge, it triggers correctly.

[image]

Don't know how to resolve it in Chrome? I've tried to clear the Cache. Also the same result.

Comment: Try `method: 'POST'` instead of `type: 'POST'`

Comment: What effect do the querystring parameters in the first screenshot have on the logic? Are there any errors in the console? Is this AJAX request made when a form is submit and that form submission is not prevented? My point here is there's several reasons this could be happening, but without seeing a more complete example of the code creating the problem, we cannot help you effectively. Any attempt to do so would be a guess.

Comment: We're going to need a [mre] of the issue. jQuery $.ajax on its own doesn't do this, or at least not differently in different browsers, AFAIK. I wonder if there's some other JS issue perhaps causing a form to be submitted directly instead of some JS firing, or something like that. Although hard to see what would go wrong in Chrome but not Edge these days, they are very compatible.

Comment: `"script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, _=[TIMESTAMP], to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests. Prior to jQuery 3.5.0, unsuccessful HTTP responses with a script Content-Type were still executed.`  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The issue is in handling the request via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` or `http://localhost:8000/`. I've posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to access the server, I've received the error in Chrome, but not in Edge.

Whereas `http://localhost:8000/` to access the server, performs correctly the `POST` method in both Chrome and Edge browsers.

So, now I'm using `http://localhost:8000/`.

Answer (score -1):

The `405 Method Not Allowed` and `Request Method: GET` are a clear sign that the chrome browser use the default method GET.

You can try `method: 'POST'` instead of `type: 'POST'` as already mentioned by @aynber, but it would only solve the problem if you are using an old jQuery Version.

[See jQuery ajax documentation for more information](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> 'type' is an alias for 'method'. You should use 'type' if you're using versions of
> jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: `it would only solve the problem if you are using an old jQuery Version`...no, it's the opposite. "type" and "method" are both valid from 1.9 onwards. but if OP was using <1.9.0 then changing from "type" to "method" would _cause_ a problem, not solve it, because in those old versions it doesn't recognise "method". So this isn't the solution.